# Root is mounted as read only

Tags: linux, debian

After btrfs migration root folder mounted as read only I can’t start gdm service.  I can remount using “mount -o remount,rw /“ but after reboot it’s goes back read only.

Comment: Check the fstab and grub command line.

Comment: @symcbean whem o remouting its says fstab igroing line. Line 11 is UUID / btrfs default,compress=lzo, autodefrag,ssd,space_cache, subvol=@. Seems right to me.

Comment: That makes no sense. If you have relevant log entries please copy and paste them here.

Comment: @symcbean update-grub2 says: os-proper will not be executed to detect other bootable partitons

Comment: @symcbean after remounting / with remount,rw I can start gdm but I can not login. It's says "Could not get a valid context for the user"

Comment: @pirekare this site is not a forum ... please do not put information into comments ... edit the question instead ... there is an edit button for that ... the comments are not part of the question here ... delete the comments, because they are just clutter